# Component is undefined when using forwardRef and exported

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, ecmascript-6

I have an application that is written in Typescript, and uses Webpack with the ts-loader plugin to pack the application and serve it whilst running in dev mode.

I am trying to write a component in one file that is wrapped in `React.forwardRef` before being exported. I can create a component that works with `React.forwardRef`, but as soon as I export it I get an error saying that the value is undefined. I get this error regardless of whether I actually import the component in another file, or use it in the file it is defined in.

```
// This works fine
const Component = (props: any, ref: any) => <div ref={ref}>hello</div>
const ForwardedComponent = forwardRef(Component)
```

```
// This doesn't work:
const Component = (props: any, ref: any) => <div ref={ref}>hello</div>
export const ForwardedComponent = forwardRef(Component)
```

```
// Somehow this works!
const Component = (props: any, ref: any) => <div ref={ref}>hello</div>
const ForwardedComponent = forwardRef(Component)
export const ReExportedComponent = ForwardedComponent
```

The error I see when I try and export the component

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: ForwardedComponent is not defined
```

Any ideas what could be going on here?

Versions used:

```
"react": "^17.0.2",
"webpack": "^5.0.0",
"typescript": "^4.2.4",
"ts-loader": "8.3.0",
```

Comment: I think it might be useful if you provide your package.json and webpack config files.